# Status - 405 Not Allowed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am writing a code for a sample login with hardcode value..

```js
function wrong() {
  if (confirm("Wrong Credentials! Try again!")) {
    location.reload()
  } else {
    location.reload()
  }
}


function openLoginPage(uname, pwd) {
  if (uname.value == 'test' && pwd.value == 'test') {
    window.open("login.html", "_self");
    return true;
  } else {
    wrong()
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="login.html" onsubmit="return openLoginPage(uname,pwd)" method="POST">
  <div class="login form"> <label for="uname">Username:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="uname" placeholder="test" name="uname" value=""> <br>
    <label for="pwd">Password:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="pwd" placeholder="test" name="pwd" value=""><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Login"></input>
  </div>
</form>
```

It returns a 405 error when the condition is satisfied. Please correct my mistake.  Thanks you. You guys are the best :)

Answer (score 0):

A 405 status means [method not allowed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405). You're requesting login.html with a [GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) and I suspect your server only responds to [POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) requests for that.

If you navigate to login.html via the location bar in your browser do you also get a 405?

Comment: No, at that time I don't